# fdisk command can not find disk in bash script

Tags: bash, disk

I have made a bash script named format.sh which should format a disk. The following steps must be implemented:

1. delete existing partition.
2. create a new partition.
3. set the sector's configuration as default.
4. set partition type for linux support.
5. write changes to disk.

My main app is created using Qt creator. I want to execute `format.sh` when a `qpushbutton` is clicked. When I do that the following error apears: `fdisk: cannot open /dev/sdb: No such file or directory`
but `/dev/sdb` exists and I can format it using interactive `fdisk` command in the terminal.
here is my script code (`format.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -e 's/\s*\([\+0-9a-zA-Z]*\).*/\1/' << EOF | sudo fdisk '/dev/sdb'
 d # delete partition
 n # new partition
 p # primary partition
 1 # partition number 1
   # default, 
   # default,       
 p # print the in-memory partition table
 t  # set type
 83  # linux support
 w # write the partition table
EOF
umount  /dev/sdb1
mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sdb1
```

and here is the code which executes the bash script:

```
char cmd[100]
strcpy(cmd,"echo password | sudo -S ./format.sh");
system(cmd);
```